# What is erl.exe in coveo for sitecore

Tags: indexing, sitecore, sitecore9, coveo

When I start coveo indexing from sitecore I can see erl.exe is running in process. When I saw location of exe I found in C:\Program Files\Coveo Enterprise Search 7\Third-Party\erl5.10.3\erts-5.10.3\bin

I want to know what is the purpose of this exe?

Answer (score 1):

That's [Erlang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_(programming_language)). I'm not a Coveo specialist but it looks like [Coveo uses RabbitMQ](https://www.akshaysura.com/2015/05/01/add-max-message-limit-for-rabbitmq-for-coveo/) which has [Erlang as a dependency](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html):

> Dependencies
>   RabbitMQ requires a 64-bit supported version of Erlang for Windows to be installed. Erlang releases include a Windows installer. Erlang Solutions provide binary 64-bit builds of Erlang as well.

Answer (score 0):

The erl.exe executable is part of the Erlang/OTP distribution and is used by the Coveo Enterprise Search indexing engine. Erlang/OTP is a programming language and a runtime system used to build massively scalable, soft real-time systems with requirements on high availability.

In the context of Coveo, erl.exe is used to run the Coveo indexing engine, which crawls and indexes content from various sources and makes it searchable through Coveo's search interface. The indexing engine is a critical component of the Coveo search platform and is responsible for processing, indexing, and storing content in an efficient and scalable way.